# While statement only echoing last result

Tags: php

I am very new, I am having a small problem.. I cannot get my while loop to loop through my entire result set, it is only retrieving the last result set, and i am expecting 2 result sets.

I echo'd my query out to see the result i would get, and the echo printed out both the result sets i want to print out. Leading me to the confusion my while loop is the issue.

I have looked through lost on here but the posts i have seen it was a problem with their query, rather then their while loop. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have used different posts on here to construct my query, but i don't know where to go from here.

```
   date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

   $date = jddayofweek(unixtojd());

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID = $ID AND Day = $date";

  $results = $conn->query($sql);
  echo $sql;

 if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

        $output = "Test2" . "</br>" . $row["time"] . "</br>";
    }


           } else {

    $output = $output . "test1" . "</br>";
    }
       }
```

Comment: you are not echoing anything inside while loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not echoing anything inside your while loop.

I think you need to concatenate the variable `$output`.

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= "Test2" . "</br>" . $row["time"] . "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting the content of $output on every iteration of the loop, you should use the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to attach the value of the content to the end of the string.

```
$output .= "Test2" . "</br>" . $row["time"] . "</br>";
```

Comment: Great thank you for the link, i now understand my mistake. I would give you a up vote is i was able to

Comment: you need at least 15 reputation for do that.